# Cant get the full path of the file Django boto3 AWS S3 Ajax Upload in chunks

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, amazon-s3, boto3

I cant get the full path of the client side to upload to AWS S3

Ajax:

```
upload_file(start, path) {
    var end;
    var self = this;
    var existingPath = path;
    var formData = new FormData();
    var nextChunk = start + this.max_length + 1;
    var currentChunk = this.file.slice(start, nextChunk);
    var uploadedChunk = start + currentChunk.size
    if (uploadedChunk >= this.file.size) {
        end = 1;
    } else {
        end = 0;
    }
    formData.append('file', currentChunk);
    formData.append('filename', this.file.name);
    formData.append('end', end);
    formData.append('existingPath', existingPath);
    formData.append('nextSlice', nextChunk);
    $('.filename').text(this.file.name)
    $('.textbox').text("Uploading file")
    $.ajaxSetup({
    // make sure to send the header
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value,
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    if (self.file.size < self.max_length) {
                        var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                    } else {
                        var percent = Math.round((uploadedChunk / self.file.size) * 100);
                    }
                    $('.progress-bar').css('width', percent + '%')
                    $('.progress-bar').text(percent + '%')
                }
            });
            return xhr;
        },

        url: '/fileUploader/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        },
        success: function (res) {
            if (nextChunk < self.file.size) {
                // upload file in chunks
                existingPath = res.existingPath
                self.upload_file(nextChunk, existingPath);
            } else {
                // upload complete
                $('.textbox').text(res.data);
                alert(res.data)
            }
        }
    })
```

and my views.py

```
def create_post(request):
# s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=settings.AWS_S3_REGION_NAME, aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
categories_1 = Category.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':   
    file = request.FILES['file'].read()
    file_name_s3 = request.POST['filename']
    fileName= request.POST['filename'].replace(' ', '')
    fileName_STR = re.sub("[^A-Z]", "", fileName,0,re.IGNORECASE) + '.mp4'
    existingPath = request.POST['existingPath']
    end = request.POST['end']
    image = request.FILES.get('image', False)
    imageName = request.FILES.get('imagename', False)

    if image != False:
            image = request.FILES['image'].read()
            imageName= request.POST['imagename'].replace(' ', '')
    else:
            pass
    title = request.POST['title']
    tags = request.POST['tags']
    categories = parse_ids(request.POST['categories'])
    description = request.POST['description']
    nextSlice = request.POST['nextSlice']


    if file=="" or fileName_STR=="" or existingPath=="" or end=="" or nextSlice=="":
        res = JsonResponse({'data':'Invalid Request'})
        return res
    else:
        if existingPath == 'null':
            path = 'media/uploads/video_files/' + fileName
            
            if image != False: 
                with open(path, 'wb+') as destination: 
                    destination.write(file)
                imagePath = 'media/thumbnail/' + imageName
            else:
                pass
            if image:
                with open(imagePath, 'wb+') as destination:
                    destination.write(image)
            else: 
                pass
            
            path = 'media/uploads/video_files/' + fileName_STR
# THIS IS THE PROBLEM...................
                s3.upload_file(file_name_s3 ,bucket,str(fileName_STR))
# ............................................
            FileFolder = Post()
            FileFolder.video = 'uploads/video_files/'+fileName_STR
            FileFolder.existingPath = fileName_STR
            FileFolder.eof = end
            FileFolder.title = title
            FileFolder.author = request.user
            FileFolder.description = description

            if image == False:
                FileFolder.thumbnail = None
            else:
                FileFolder.thumbnail = 'thumbnail/' + imageName

            FileFolder.approved = True
            FileFolder.save()
            tag_list = taggit.utils._parse_tags(tags)
            FileFolder.tags.add(*tag_list)
            categories_post = Category.objects.filter(id__in=categories)
            if categories_post:
                for category in categories_post:
                    FileFolder.categories.add(category)
            if int(end):
                res = JsonResponse({'data':'Uploaded Successfully','existingPath': fileName})
            else:
                res = JsonResponse({'existingPath': fileName_STR})
            return res
        else:
            path = 'media/uploads/video_files/' + existingPath
            model_id = Post.objects.get(existingPath=existingPath)
            if model_id.title == title:
                if not model_id.eof:
                    with open(path, 'ab+') as destination: 
                        destination.write(file)
                    if int(end):
                        model_id.eof = int(end)
                        model_id.save()
                        res = JsonResponse({'data':'Uploaded Successfully','existingPath':model_id.existingPath})
                    else:
                        res = JsonResponse({'existingPath':model_id.existingPath})    
                    return res
                else:
                    res = JsonResponse({'data':'EOF found. Invalid request'})
                    return res
            else:
                res = JsonResponse({'data':'No such file exists in the existingPath'})
                return res
return render(request, 'main/create_post.html', {'categories': categories_1})
```

HOW TO GET THE PATH OF THE FILE SO I CAN UPLOAD TO AWS S3, no matter what i tried it doesnt gives me the full path

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Bones - TheArtOfCremation-tqSpI1Jm0YE-1080p.mp4'